# Android Preferences Disabling Bluetooth

Tags: android, xml, bluetooth, android-preferences, android-fragmentactivity

I have created a preferences menu using preference fragments (see below). The menu works and now I am trying to link the settings menu to actual functionality. I want to use the Bluetooth setting in the xml to disable and enable bluetooth. I know this can be done using the bluetooth.disable() function, but I wasn't sure how/where to call this. Should I be using an onSharedPreferenceChanged function? Should I create an action inside the xml? Or should I use BLUETOOTH_SERVICE somehow?

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
 import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class UserSettings extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, 
                new PrefsFragment()).commit();
}

public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.user_settings);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="BluetoothSettings">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="prefService"
        android:summary="Bluetooth Settings"
        android:title="Bluetooth" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Notifications" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="prefLockScreen"
        android:summary="Enable Notifications"
        android:title="Notify" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>

    <ListPreference
        android:key="prefUpdateFrequency"
        android:title="Notification Settings"
        android:summary="Set Specific Notification Settings"
        android:entries="@array/updateNotifications"
        android:entryValues="@array/updateNotificationValues"
        />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do.
Override OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

```
public class UserSettings extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) {

    if (key.equals("prefService")) {


               enable/disable here

    } 
}
```

Also remember to register and unregister the listener
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

Comment: Thank you!! Does the listener need to be registered in the main activity? It won't let me do it in the fragment?

Comment: public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}


    public void onPause() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}